# How do I apply 2 filters to my ElasticSearch query object?

Tags: search, lucene, indexing, elasticsearch

I want to query my index, but apply 2 filters.
First, the price and second the location.

```
var qobject = {
        query:{
            custom_score:{
                query:{
                    filtered:{
                        query:{
                            multi_match:{
                                query: q,
                                fields: ['title','description'],
                            }
                        },
                        filter:{
                            range:{
                                price: { from: 0, to: max_price }
                            },
                            geo_distance:{
                                'distance': distance + 'mi',
                                'location':{
                                    lat: lat,
                                    lon: lon
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                script: '_score + _source["price"] * 10'
            }
        }
    }

    elasticSearchClient.search('products', 'products', qobject)
```

As you can see, this query object results in an error.

However, if I **remove either range or geo_distance**, everything is fine! But I want both filters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'and'-filter.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/and-filter.html

Without testing:

```
var qobject = {
        query:{
            custom_score:{
                query:{
                    filtered:{
                        query:{
                            multi_match:{
                                query: q,
                                fields: ['title','description'],
                            }
                        },
                        filter:{
                            "and" : [
                                range:{
                                    price: { from: 0, to: max_price }
                                },
                                geo_distance:{
                                    'distance': distance + 'mi',
                                    'location':{
                                        lat: lat,
                                        lon: lon
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                script: '_score + _source["price"] * 10'
            }
        }
    }
```

explanation: the 'filter'-part of the 'filtered query' can actually be any type of filter you like, including the 'and'. Once that concept is clear, it's pretty trivial to build up complex queries / filters.

Comment: Is using "and" the same as wrapping the filter inside another filter?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Some filters like the 'and' are made especially for nesting other filters.. You could call this wrapping i suppose.

Comment: When you look at the docs you can Find and, or, not filters .. These all 'wrap' other filters ( you can nest arbitrarily deep: and inside or etc) which allows you to construct arbitrarily complex boolean queries